# Transient simulation of low-pass filters

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, spice, low-pass

I am simulating two low-pass filters with different cut-off frequencies. The first image below shows the outputs -LPF1 and LPF2- and the input -V(z)- of the both low-pass filters.
The second image shows the circuit.
Actually, I was expecting a step response function as a result, which is not the case.
How should we interpret the result? Why don't those outputs show step response behaviour? Did I something wrong? Wenn yes, how can I fix that?

[image: simulation result]

[image: circuit]

Edit: As you said, I let the circuit simulate for 10ms. Now I see, that the settling time for the second low-pass filter is too high compared to the first low-pass filter. Now the result makes sense.

[image: 10ms simulation time]

Comment: *I was expecting a step response function as a result* Then you have to make the input voltage a step, is your input voltage a step function? (You can probably guess that it is not). Read the documentation on how to set the PULSE source such that it will give you a single step function.

Comment: Why would you expect a step response, when your input is a saw tooth?

Comment: You could consider the triangle input a "step" if its average would be different than zero and its frequency much greater than the corner frequency of the filters, but it's better to just make it a step (try `PWL(0 0 1u 1)`, for example, or `PULSE(0 1 0 1u 0 1k 2k)`. *BUT* you need to simulate for the proper time span -- here you're only simulating for 50 \$\mu\$s. Also, you could use larger values for caps and smaller for resistors.

Comment: You're right. In that case there won't be any step function. But I would like to know, what this result says.

Comment: *But I would like to know, what this result says.* Your simulation simply does not make sense. You apply a **1 MHz** signal at the input while the filters are 100 Hz and 10 kHz **Low pass** filters. How do such filters respond to a 1 MHz signal? Also you only simulate 50 us. A 100 Hz filter has a time constant of around 1/ 100 Hz = 0.01 s = 10 ms so to see the response of a 100 Hz filter, you will need to simulate for a couple of times that number so 100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

To exemplify what I said, here is a simulation with two, identical filters (Bessel, 1 kHz, no frequency scaling), both driven by a regular step source of 1 V, and the other with a triangle wave (to keep your attempt) with a frequency 10 times larger (10 kHz) than the corner frequency, but having the same 1 V average (`x` input has `a` output, `y` input has `b` output):

[image: test]

The inputs are modelled as `pwl 0 0 1u 1` for `x` and `pulse 0 2 0 {0.5/f} {0.5/f} 0 {1/f}` for `y` (with `.param f=10k` defined). As you can see, the underlying step response is there, but it is superimposed with the response from the triangle wave. Which is basic convolution at work. Also, the simulation time has to include all the transients, not just a few periods of the input signal -- after all, the interest is the *filter*'s response, not the input's.

The problem is that you can't really see the true step response due to the filtered harmonic content of the triangle wave. If you increase the frequency to be 100x larger (`.param f=100k`), you get these responses, virtually identical:

[image: same]

But the requirement is to have that average different than zero, otherwise what you get is the *impulse* response, plus harmonics from the input (the source is now `pwl repeat forever 0 0 {.25/f} 1 {.75/f} -1 {1/f} 0 endrepeat` -- note the requirement to start at zero):

[image: impulse]

As for why would anyone want to simulate a 100 kHz triangle waveform to mimic a simple step input, it's beyond me.

Answer (score -1):

> *Actually, I was expecting a step response function as a result, which
> is not the case.*

If you want a step response then you must input a step. Your input source is a triangle wave at about 1 MHz from what I see in your green waveform.

> *How should we interpret the result?*

You shouldn't; fix the input source to be a step change.

> *how can I fix that?*

I think you probably realize how to do that now. In case you don't, make the duration of the pulse bigger than the period and use the rise time value to produce an initial fast slope. Something like this: -

`DC 0 AC 1 0 Pulse 0 5 1m 10u 10n 10m 1m`

That's a pulse that begins at 0 volts and rises to 5 volts after an initial 1 ms second delay. The rise time is 10 μs and the fall time (irrelevant in this example) is 10 ns. The period is 1 ms but, this is far exceeded by the pulse duration of 10ms.

Comment: Who downvoted this answer and, for what reason?